# Attribute directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a attribute directive that will insert a label before the input field.    Judging by the alert statement, the html looks correct.   However I am not compiling or doing the angular element correctly.   Any help would would be much appreciated.

The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/2suL9/

This is the JS code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('makeLabel', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, inputFld, attrs) {
            var ForInput = attrs['name'];
            var LabelSize = attrs['labelSize'];
            var LabelText = attrs['makeLabel'];
            var htmlStart = '<label for="' + ForInput + '" class="label-control ' + LabelSize + '">';
            var htmlStar = '';
            if (attrs['required'] ) {
                htmlStar = '<span style="color:red">*</span>';
            }
            var htmlEnd = LabelText + ":</label> ";
            var htmlTotal = htmlStart + htmlStar + htmlEnd;
            alert(htmlTotal);
            // Now add it before the input
            var newLabel = angular.element(htmlTotal);
            inputFld.prepend(($compile(htmlTotal)));
        }
    };
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form name="TestLabelForm" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="Simple" required="" make-label="Test Label" label-size="col-md-7" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br />
        Should look like
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <form name="ExampleForm" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Simple2" class="col-md-7"><span style="color:red">*</span>Test Label:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Simple2" required="" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Get Javascript -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/TestLabelAttr.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works for me, what do you expect exactly ?

Comment: "I am not compiling or doing the angular element correctly" means??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you see the DOM Exception, which was thrown? It could not find the elements, which you created. You have to use `document.createElement()` and introduce the newly created element to the scope via `$compile(scope)(newElement)`. Here is a working fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/2suL9/26/ Please note that I didn't implement the if condition of your example, you have to add it!

The javascript part looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('makeLabel', function ($compile) {
    return function (scope, inputFld, attrs) {
        var el = inputFld[0];
        var newEl = document.createElement("label");
        newEl.setAttribute("for", attrs['name']);
        newEl.setAttribute("class", "label-control");
        var subEl = document.createElement("span");
        subEl.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
        subEl.innerHTML = "*";
        var endText = document.createTextNode("Test Label:");

        $compile(scope)(newEl);
        $compile(scope)(subEl);
        $compile(scope)(endText);
        newEl.appendChild(subEl);
        newEl.appendChild(endText);
        inputFld.parent().prepend(newEl);
    }
});
```

Note: Changing the dom elements outside of the directive is not a good practice. Rather use another directive for the label, which should be shown in front of the input. You can centralise the logic in your controller and use broadcast to inform the directives, when they should change.

Comment: It should be `$compile(element)(scope)`.